# Why can breakpoints not be set in some file while other files are OK?

Tags: debugging, driver, windbg, breakpoints, debug-symbols

I'm debugging a project with WinDBG. I run across a weird problem:

Say the driver image is named foo.sys, and there are two source files named 
src_1.c and src_2.c; there is a function named `void f();` in src_2.c.

**Step 1:**

I use OSRLoader to load foo.sys into kernel successfully.

**Step 2:**

I use command `lm` to check if the symbol has been correctly loaded

```
kd> lm
...
...
8bad3000 8baec400   foo    (private pdb symbols)  d:\symbols\private\foo.pdb
...
...
```

and use command `!itoldyouso` ti verify

```
kd> !itoldyouso foo d:\symbols\private\foo.pdb

foo.sys
    Timestamp: 526DC759
  SizeOfImage: 19400
          pdb: f:\projects\foo\objchk_wxp_x86\i386\foo.pdb
      pdb sig: 851C2562-6FE3-4391-88C6-320253CC3372
          age: 1

foo.pdb
      pdb sig: 851C2562-6FE3-4391-88C6-320253CC3372
          age: 1
```

That proves the symbol has been correctly loaded.

**Step 3:**

I can set breakpoints in src_1.c at any valid code line.

**Step 4:**

I **CANNOT** set any breakpoints in src_2.c, even if I close and reload src_2.c 
from the correct location. However, if I use `bu foo!f` to set a breakpoint on `f`, 
it works.

After I have set a breakpoint on `foo!f`, the execution will be broken at `foo!f` as 
expected, and I can do source-level debugging step-by-step.

However, even I can do source-level debugging step-by-step in src_2.c, I still 
cannot set any breakpoint in src_2.c through pressing F9.

What's the root cause?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you set using _F9_? Your source and pdb might be out of sync (source is modified).

Comment: @Rohan, F9 has no effect. kd> !itoldyouso foo d:\symbols\private\foo.pdb shows they are in sync.

Comment: what is the output from `x foo!f`? is there a match? What command are you using for setting src breakpoints or are you just doing it via `F9` with source file open? Have you turned optimisation off `/Od /Oi` see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link?